# Undefined method error when using distinctBy returned by stream created from Vavr List.distinctBy

Tags: java, collections, java-stream, vavr

I want to use `List.distinctBy` to filter lists provided by [Vavr](https://github.com/vavr-io/vavr).

I added this dependency in my pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.vavr</groupId>
    <artifactId>vavr-kotlin</artifactId>
    <version>0.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```

but when I use it in the code

```java
menuPriceByDayService
        .findAllOrderByUpdateDate(menu, DateUtils.semestralDate(), 26)
        .stream()
        .distinctBy(MenuPriceByDay::getUpdateLocalDate)
        .map(cp -> cp.getUpdateLocalDate())
        .sorted()
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

I have a compilation error:

> The method distinctBy(MenuPriceByDay::getUpdateLocalDate) is undefined for the type Stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `List.distinctBy` is a method on `io.vavr.collection.List`, and you are trying to call it on a `java.util.stream.Stream`.

You can use e.g. [`StreamEx`](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) instead:

```
StreamEx.of(
    menuPriceByDayService
        .findAllOrderByUpdateDate(menu, DateUtils.semestralDate(), 26)
        .stream())
    .distinct(MenuPriceByDay::getUpdateLocalDate)
    .map // etc
```

But for this specific case you really don't need it because you are doing a `map` **by the same function** afterwards. So it should be equivalent to

```
menuPriceByDayService
    .findAllOrderByUpdateDate(menu, DateUtils.semestralDate(), 26)
    .stream()
    .map(cp -> cp.getUpdateLocalDate())
    .distinct()
    .sorted()
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

(assuming `getUpdateLocalDate` is a pure function).